# Redirect all requests to a certain folder using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I really need some help on a HTACCESS file - if someone could help me it would be very much appreciated.

All I want to do is redirect any request to the folder /test/

So if you go to my website http://www.example.com, I want it to auto-redirect via the HTACCESS file to /test/ directory!

Every time I try to do it, it causes a redirect loop! Help! :(

If anyone has any idea of how exactly I could do this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks for you're help.

**Please note:** I am trying to redirect from one website to the same website but just in a different folder. i.e. I want example.com to redirect to example.com/test/

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/test
RewriteRule ^ /test [R=301]
```

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
redirect / http://www.expample.com/test/
```

Comment: Hi, That causes a redirect loop. :|

Comment: what's in your `/test/` path?